# TabHost inside ScrollView sets focus to content and scrolls

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, android-tabhost

I have a Fragment that has contains lots of info (article) with a tabhost at a bottom with other articles as a couple of listViews. The problem is when i select tabs my scrollView scrolls to encompass the listview (actually just scroll everything so the first item of the list view is the first thing on the screen), which i do not want.

I need listViews inside ScrollView because there are a lot of information to show + additional related articles and such, and the layout is much longer than the screen. I solved the problem of listviews inside scrollview, just can't figure out how to disable
setting focus on tab click.

here is my layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/category_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:src="@drawable/currency_flag_eur" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.24"
                android:src="@drawable/currency_flag_eur" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.29"
                android:src="@drawable/currency_flag_eur" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/ticker" />

        <TabHost
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/category_top_news"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </ListView>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/category_most_read"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </ListView>

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/category_facebook"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                    </ListView>
                </FrameLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </TabHost>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone was wandering i solved my problem so i set my listviews inside my to

```
setFocusable(false)
```

and they stopped jerking around.